# Function/helper to lookup self from object

Tags: typescript

The API for value lookup exists on the collection, which makes sense and works in the vast majority of cases. Curious if an API exists to go the other way:

```
const store = {key: 1}
const getKey = () => "key" as (string | undefined) // might be compute-heavy
const result = store[getKey()] // undefined cannot be used as an index type. Can't do this.

const result = getKey() && store[getKey()] // needed to call getKey() twice here, meaning I can't inline efficiently

const result = getKey()?.valueIn(store) // would be awesome if this returned 1
valueIn(store) {store[self]} // under the hood
```

Comment: Just use an extra variable. Or even make a function. Don't jump through hoops for such a trivial piece of functionality.

Comment: Sooooo something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m369yN)? I'm not sure what you're asking for, but you should really follow VLAZ's comment and *don't* do this.

Comment: A helper function is probably easy enough(I was just curious if something builtin already existed though). I added the helper below as an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose making a helper is easy enough...

```
const maybeGet = (store, key) => key && store[key];

const result = maybeGet(store, getKey())
```